# SQL create a column with the mean of the category plus some filters

Tags: sql

My aim is to create two columns im my sql table (let's call them NEW_COL1 & NEW_COL2)

First, in NEW_COL1 I would like to have the mean of a certain variable (price in my example) of all the observations that belong to the same category (BRAND) and are close in distance regarding one other variable (KM).

Example:
For the first observation (an Audi with 60 000km) I would like to have a column next to it with the mean price of all Audi that has 20 000 km more or 20 000 km less

Secondly, I do not know how to do a simple operation, compute the frequency of the category in % (without convoluted joins)

What I would like to achieve ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDCcU.jpg)):

```
+ -- + ------- + ------ + ----- + -------- + ----------- + _------- + -------------- +
| ID | Brand   | KM     | Price | NEW_COL1 |             | NEW_COL2 |                |
+ -- + ------- + ------ + ----- + -------- + ----------- + _------- + -------------- +
| 1  | audi    | 60000  | 15000 | 14000    | MEAN(1,2)   | 45%      | #audi/total    |
| 2  | audi    | 80000  | 13000 | 13333.33 | MEAN(2,3,4) | 45%      |                |
| 3  | audi    | 90000  | 12000 | 12500    | MEAN(2,3)   | 45%      |                |
| 4  | audi    | 120000 | 15000 | 7500     | MEAN(4,5)   | 45%      |                |
| 5  | audi    | 130000 | 15000 | 7500     | MEAN(4,5)   | 45%      |                |
| 6  | Porsche | 60000  | 30000 | 28000    | MEAN(6,7)   | 45%      | #porsche/total |
| 7  | Porsche | 80000  | 26000 | 26666.67 | MEAN(6,7,8) | 45%      |                |  
| 8  | Porsche | 90000  | 24000 | 25000    | MEAN(7,8)   | 45%      |                |
| 9  | Porsche | 120000 | 16000 | 15000    | MEAN(9,10)  | 45%      |                |
| 10 | Porsche | 130000 | 14000 | 15000    | MEAN(9,10)  | 45%      |                |
| 11 | Porsche | 170000 | 8000  | 8000     | MEAN(11)    | 45%      |                |
+ -- + ------- + ------ + ----- + -------- + ----------- + _------- + -------------- +
```

Do you have any idea?

Editor's Note: Based on the description in the column after NEW_COL1 and the ordering of the data, I changed the KM for ID 4,5,9,10 to have 120,000 and 130,000. Also, the original calculation of some of the means was wrong, so I updated that too.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Which dbms??????  The syntax is different for different dbms.  It's useless if someone post answer to the wrong dbms.  So tag properly!!!!

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use correlated subqueries.  Here is an example:

```
select c.*,
       (select avg(c2.price)
        from cars c2
        where c2.brand = c.brand and
              c2.km between c.km - 20000 and c.km + 20000
       ) as avg_price
from cars c;
```

You can use `count(*)` instead of `avg()` to get the number of "neighbors".

Comment: Thank you!!! it is exactly what i was looking for. The only problem is that it is very slow (600k rows)  :o  is there a more efficient in my situation?

Comment: @MichelGala . . . You might want to ask another question, asking about performance.  But an index on `cars(brand, km)` should help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to leave the answer pretty generic sql since you did not supply a RDBMS. A join might be a little faster for you. To get NEW_COL1, try this

```
select a.*, AVG(cast(b.Price as float)) as NEW_COL1
    from Cars a
    left join Cars b
        on b.Brand = a.Brand
        and b.KM between a.KM - 20000 and a.KM + 20000
    group by a.ID, a.Brand, a.KM, a.Price
```

Personally, I like to use cross applies for this type of query, but not every version of sql supports that (I'm looking at you, MySQL).

Getting NEW_COL2 is a little trickier, but something like this should do the trick:

```
select a.*, AVG(cast(b.Price as float)) as NEW_COL1
    , cast(cast(( select COUNT(*)
                    from Cars x
                    where x.Brand = a.Brand
                    group by Brand
    ) as float) / ( select COUNT(*) from Cars) * 100 as int) as NEW_COL2
    from Cars a
    left join Cars b
        on b.Brand = a.Brand
        and b.KM between a.KM - 20000 and a.KM + 20000
    group by a.ID, a.Brand, a.KM, a.Price
```